# Can I edit the XML in a SSIS package?

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, etl

My company has hundreds of SSIS packages that will be impacted by some required SQL table changes.    The changes involve a handful of columns whose length is being increased and the addition of another column.  I'm hoping to find some way to update the metadata for the OLE DB Destination without manually opening each package.

Is there any way to do a Find/Replace type of operation on the XML contained within the .dtsx files, or is this just asking for trouble?

Other suggestions?

Comment: I upgraded some connection manager driver software I was using. This prevented the legacy SSIS packages from loading in the UI. I edited the XML to replace the old connection manager with a new one and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a column, it's a bit trickier than simply doing a find/replace since you will need to generate a GUID for that column and make sure all references are updated to point at it.

As T McKeown stated, manually editing the SSIS XML has a very high failure rate, but it's not impossible.

If you have an intern who can walk and chew gum, I would throw them at it as a first option.

Comment: I don't see a GUID associated with the existing columns but there is a lineage ID.  Maybe this is what you're referring to?  I'm assuming this needs to be unique within a given package.  On top of that, there's also some auto-generated VB code within the assembly for each column contained in the metadata.

It's looking like this approach may be as much of a pain as opening each package.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the lineage ID.  It does need to be unique to the package; possibly it needs to be unique in the solution but I haven't tested that.  It is a major pain.  I'm going down that road because I have to map 600 column fixed width files from time to time; otherwise I would just do it manually.
Pour some fresh coffee, set your brain to idle, and enjoy some safe, stable drudgery.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what you are doing absolutely ok, it's a lot easier than bringing up that monster IDE.  I've done it in the past, just make sure you copy it before.